# Win 7: Sharing - Folder - Can't stop sharing with other user on same machine

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

Win 7: I tried to stop sharing a folder from my user (administrator), but later when I logged in from a different administrator user, the "click continue to permanently get access to this folder" dialogue turned up and to my utter dismay, once I clicked continue, the folder opened and its contents revealed. I need to stop sharing the folder with any user on the machine and the network (I use a wireless router for broadband internet). Please help!

Comment: You can't. Anything you do as an Administrator can later be undone by (another) Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following two ways to stop folder sharing:

Way1:

1. Open computer Management->Shared Folders->Shares.
2. Right click the specific folder we want to stop sharing.
3. Select "Stop Sharing".
   [image]

[Stop Sharing Computer Folders - Windows 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4q1YmDcdV7I)

Way2:

1. Right click the specific folder we want to stop sharing.
2. Select "Properties", click "Sharing".
3. Click " Advanced Sharing".
4. Uncheck " Share this folder".
5. Click "Apply" and "OK".

[image]

[How to Remove Sharing of Folder and Drive in Windows 7, 8 & 8.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN9FKHWbW48)